# Aligning ggplot multiple faceted plots and custom font

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I've got some data that's broken down into three subcategories (A, B and C). I've used ggplot's `facet_wrap` function to plot it by these subcategories, all good so far.

However, the subcategories for each `A` don't overlap. When plotting the different categories with different line types, or colours it becomes very hard to work out the distinction between them (particularly B6 and B8 in the example).

Code I've got so far, (forgive the semi-obfuscatd names, it's semi-sensitive) basic loading:

```
library('ggplot2')
library('extrafonts')
loadfonts()
all_d <- read.table(url('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=WArS8GZM'), header=TRUE)
```

So here's what I've got for the plain faceted plot:

```
ggplot(all_d, aes(x=Q, y=T, linetype=B)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line") +
  facet_wrap(A~M, scales='free', ncol=2)
```

Which results in below plot, as you can see the lines don't really differentiate too well.
[image]

To solve this, the only solution I've found is the plot them separately as ggplot doesn't handle restarting the line types(?)

Now comes the "fun" part. The axes have different scales in them, and the legends have different lengths, so lining up the images becomes an issue to say the least. After some mangling, and finagling:

```
g_legend <- function(a.gplot){ 
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot)) 
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box") 
  return(tmp$grobs[[leg]])
}    

get_plot <- function(data, C) {
  data <- data[which(data$M == C),]
  p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Q, y=T, linetype=B)) + 
    theme(legend.position='bottom') +
    stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line") +
    labs(x='Q', y='T')
  p
}

a1 <- all_d[which(all_d$A == 'A1'),]
a2 <- all_d[which(all_d$A == 'A2'),]
a3 <- all_d[which(all_d$A == 'A3'),]

plots <- list(get_plot(a1, 'C1'), get_plot(a1, 'C2'), 
          get_plot(a2, 'C1'), get_plot(a2, 'C2'),
          get_plot(a3, 'C1'), get_plot(a3, 'C2'))
grobs <- list()
widths <- list()
legend <- list()

for (i in 1:length(plots)){
  legend[[i]] <- g_legend(plots[[i]])
  grobs[[i]] <- ggplotGrob(plots[[i]] + theme(legend.position='none'))
  widths[[i]] <- grobs[[i]]$widths[2:5]
}
maxwidth <- do.call(grid::unit.pmax, widths)
for (i in 1:length(grobs)){
  grobs[[i]]$widths[2:5] <- as.list(maxwidth)
}
t <- gtable(widths=unit(c(1,1), "null"), heights=unit(rep(c(.5,6,.5), 3), "null"))
t <- gtable_add_grob(t, textGrob("A1"), 1, 1, 1, 2)
t <- gtable_add_grob(t, grobs[[1]], 2, 1)
t <- gtable_add_grob(t, grobs[[2]], 2, 2)
t <- gtable_add_grob(t, legend[[1]], 3, 1, 3, 2)
t <- gtable_add_grob(t, textGrob("A2"), 4, 1, 4, 2)
t <- gtable_add_grob(t, grobs[[3]], 5, 1)
t <- gtable_add_grob(t, grobs[[4]], 5, 2)
t <- gtable_add_grob(t, legend[[3]], 6, 1, 6, 2)
t <- gtable_add_grob(t, textGrob("A3"), 7, 1, 7, 2)
t <- gtable_add_grob(t, grobs[[5]], 8, 1)
t <- gtable_add_grob(t, grobs[[6]], 8, 2)
t <- gtable_add_grob(t, legend[[5]], 9, 1, 9, 2)

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(t)
```

Which results in below plot, everything is lined up, with the same plot areas, legends are at the very least, not a problem being on the bottom.

[image]

**However**, I want to plot these plots using the Computer Modern font so that it fits with the rest of my latex document. Adding `+ theme_grey(base_family='CM Roman')` to the separate graphs results in:

```
Error in grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  polygon edge not found
In addition: Warning message:
In grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  no font could be found for family "CM Roman"
```

But doing `loadfonts()` from `extrafonts` shows the CM Roman font has been loaded. The font was installed using `font_install('fontcm')`

Adding the same theme specifying the font works with the first facetted plot.